# Prevent a numeric from being converted into a factor

Tags: r

I'm building a table from a CSV file.  When the file is initially loaded I need to load as characters.

```
datset <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character")
```

I have function to convert a factor containing number (from other stack q)

```
as.numeric.factor <- function(x) {as.numeric(levels(x))[x]}
```

I clean up the file with

```
i<-17
datset[datset=="Not Available"]<-NA
datset<-datset[complete.cases(datset[,i]),]
x<- as.numeric.factor(datset[, i])
```

The datset table contains lots of columns I don't need so I build a new table :

```
dat <- data.frame(cbind("HospitalName"= datset[,2], "State"= datset[,7],"Rating" = x))
```

My problem is that even though x is numeric, it gets turned into a factor when loaded to the dataframe.  I can verify this from debug mode with :

```
class(x)
"Numeric"

class(dat[,3])
"Factor"
```

In later code I'm trying to sort the Rating column but it's failing due it being a factor - I guess.

I've even tried appending `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to `read.csv` but this has no effect.

How can I prevent x from being converted into a factor when loading to a DF?

Comment: Why don't you use the appropriate arguments in `read.csv` instead? There is an `na.strings` argument and you could import the column as numeric.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the error when `x <- factor(1:10)`: after transformation with `as.numeric.factor` and putting it in a data frame, it remains a `numeric`. @Henrik's comment is, I think, right on where there is a problem: what happens when you remove `cbind`?

Comment: In addition to the comment of @Roland, I think the `data.frame(cbind` step is problematic. The `cbind` step results in a matrix. A matrix can only hold type of values (see coercion hierarchy in the **Value** section of `?matrix`). When you then apply `data.frame` on a character matrix, values are converted to `factor` (see `stringsAsFactors` argument in `?data.frame`). See also `options`; `stringsAsFactors`.

Comment: The csv is 40 columns wide so to spec it out will be pain. I'd rather understand why R is messing with the data type.

Comment: Pay attention to Henrik. Note the examples in `?data.frame`, which allow for constructs like `data.frame(x = ...,y = ...)`, which is how you should be using the function. `data.frame(cbind())` is a very bad habit.

Comment: @LeeH You don't have to specify the col classes (`read.csv` can do this automatically), but you could: `colclasses <- rep("character, 40);  colclasses[7] <- "numeric"`

Comment: `as.numeric.factor <- function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))`

Comment: Henrik  - so the fact I'm making a matrix via one cbind with a mix of characters and numeric is being converted to factor. I see.   If this doesn't work how do I add the 3rd column to the dataframe without it being converted?

Comment: `data.frame(HospitalName = dataset[,2],state = dataset[,7],rating = x)`, just like I mentioned, and just like the examples in `?data.frame`.

Comment: I missed a "one" in my comment. It should be "A matrix can only hold **one** type of values.

Comment: @joran - apologies I missed your comment.  I'll give it a try.  Thanks.

Comment: @joran - this solved my problem - how can I give you the answer?

Comment: @roland thanks for letting me know read.csv is much more powerful that it first seems.  As they say there are many ways to skin a cat. I'll rewrite this when I get through learning read.csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Henrik explained in his comment, this:

```
dat <- data.frame(cbind("HospitalName"= datset[,2], "State"= datset[,7],"Rating" = x))
```

is a poor way to construct a data frame. `cbind` converts everything to a matrix, which can only hold a single data type. Hence the coercion.

It would be better to do:

```
dat <- data.frame(HospitalName = dataset[,2],state = dataset[,7],rating = x)
```

However, it is also true as Roland mentioned that you should be able to specify this one column to be numeric when reading the data in via:

```
colclasses <- rep("character", 40)
colclasses[7] <- "numeric"
```

and then passing that in `read.csv`.

Comment: Thanks @joran.  I'm still getting to grips with the class system in R.  I understand completely where I was going wrong thanks to eloquent explanation